# jquery .show() and back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get my web page to look the same when the user returns using the back button.  In my example, click a checkbox and then click the url it shows.  Once you get to google or yahoo, click the back button and notice the url is no longer displayed.  The check box is still checked, but no url.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#googlelink").hide();
  $("#yahoolink").hide();
  
  $("#google").click(function() {
    if($('#google:checked').length) {
      $("#googlelink").show();
    } else {
      $("#googlelink").hide();
    }
  });
  
  $("#yahoo").click(function() {
    if($('#yahoo:checked').length) {
      $("#yahoolink").show();
    } else {
      $("#yahoolink").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="check">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="google" id="google" />
    <label for="google">show google link</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="yahoo" id="yahoo" />
    <label for="yahoo">show yahoo link</label>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="googlelink">
  <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
<div id="yahoolink">
  <a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo.com</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minify your code and trigger the change event on DOMReady.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#googlelink, #yahoolink").hide();

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() {
           var id = '#' + this.id + 'link';
           $(id).css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
    }).change();

    //$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    //   var id = '#' + this.id + 'link';
    //   $(id).css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
    //})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like browser behavior. It is common for Chrome, for example, to empty all text fields when navigating forward and back between pages, even if some options in a form are set.